# Android Room Relation returns an invalid list

Tags: android, relational-database, android-room, android-room-relation

I have a query with a complex relation.

```
data class GameWithHouseworkResult(
    @Embedded val game:GameClass,
    @Relation(
            entity = GameHouseworkResult::class,
            parentColumn = "gameId",
            entityColumn = "houseworkId" ,
            associateBy = Junction(value=GameHouseworkResult::class)
    )
    val houseworkAndResult: List<HouseworkAndResult>
)
```

I have 3 entities and one additional class

```
    @Entity
    class GameClass(
        @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
        var gameId: Int = 0,
        val mainPlayer:String,
        var secondPlayer:String=""
    }
    
    @Entity
    data class HouseworkClass(
        @PrimaryKey
        val houseworkId: Int,
        val name:String,
        val score:Int
        ) {
    }
    
    @Entity(primaryKeys = ["gameId", "houseworkId"])
    class GameHouseworkResult(
        var gameId: Long,
        val houseworkId:Long,
        val userToken:String,
        val isDone:Boolean?= null) {
    }

data class HouseworkAndResult(
    @Embedded val gameHouseworkResult:GameHouseworkResult,
    @Relation(
        parentColumn = "houseworkId",
        entityColumn = "houseworkId"
    )
    val housework: HouseworkClass
)
```

GameHouseworkResult is a binder class, it contains the following data
[image]

```
    @Transaction
    @Query("SELECT * FROM GameClass where gameId=:id")
    suspend fun getGameWithHouseworkResult(id:Long): GameWithHouseworkResult
```

when I send a request with `gameId = 26`, I should get a list(houseworkAndResult) with five elements, but I get a list of 10 elements, and each one says that `gameId = 26`.
Most likely this is due to the same houseworkId, but I cannot understand where I went wrong when drawing up the relations. Please HELP me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't worry, I've found a solution. I confused the @relation and used many-to-many instead of one-to-many. Correct code

```
data class GameWithHouseworkResult(
    @Embedded val game:GameClass,
    @Relation(
            entity = GameHouseworkResult::class,
            parentColumn = "gameId",
            entityColumn = "gameId"
    )
    val houseworkAndResult: List<HouseworkAndResult>
)
```